# Adding imageView over another imageView cause resizing of the bottom one.How to prevent?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I have following problem:
in my layout xml I have relative layout in which is placed an ImageView(drawable from app /res folder, is drawn).

I need to add programmatically another ImageView(with another drawable from app resources) exactly on the same place as the initial one and to perform an animation on it.

I almost succeed ,a add new ImageView with new drawable and the layout params taken from the inital ImageView, and perform the animation on it,but the initial ImageView(which is bellow the newly added) is getting smaller - resize itself without reason(the other childs are OK).

How to prevent this?the both images are exactly the same width and height and I need to remain the same...
Thanks in advance.

P.S. update the question .

```
> <RelativeLayout> .... ... ... <ImageView deck1 > centerverticaly and
> leftof(other UI component) - this is the initial imageview and
> represents deck full of cards.... ... <ImageView deck2>
> centerverticaly and rightof(other UI component) - this is the second
> deck where the cards should be opened.... ... </RelativeLayout>
```

now I need to take a single card from deck1 and using animation to place it on deck2.
so I do the following:

```
if(animatingView==null){
ImageView animatingview = new ImageView(this.context);
animatingView.setImageBitmap(R.drawable.backofthecard);
animatinView.setLayoutParams(deck1.getLayoutParams);
RelativeLayout.add(animatingView);
}else{
animatingView.setVisible(visible);
}
animatingView.startAnimation(deckTranslateAnimation);

.
.
..
OnAnimationEnd{animatingView.setVisible(invisible)}
```

all of the drawables are equal(width and height),so I expect that there won't be any problems ,but when the animatingView is added to a Layout - deck1 get smaller,resize itself,it is still clickable and displayed but is smaller(and because it gets smaller all the other childs that depend on it,change their places...)

Sorry I didn't use the real code and xml,but right now I am not in front of them...

Edit:Solved.Here is the code:

```
if(animatingView==null){
                animatingView = new ImageView(context);
                animatingView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(animatingView.getDrawable().getMinimumWidth(), animatingView.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight());
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, this.getDeckView().getCardView().getId());
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, this.getDeckView().getCardView().getId());
                animatingView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the code you are using? 
Anyway, i think it is better to use FrameLayout to show views that may overlapped to each other. My first thought without seeing the code is to wrap the existing ImageView with FrameLayout. Then when you want to programmatically add new ImageView, you can do it by adding it as FrameLayout's child. FrameLayout renders view in different layer, so the old one should not be affected when you do something with the newly added view.

[updated]

I just tried to implement placing imageview over another imageview. Anyway, I don't seem to get the problem on the size of the overlapped image. Here are my implementation. Please try this and see if it worked or not. You may have to change some variables though.

.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ImageStackActivity extends Activity {

    Context context;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    ImageView deck1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context = this.getApplicationContext();
        deck1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.deck1);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.photo3);
                img.setLayoutParams(deck1.getLayoutParams());
                relativeLayout.addView(img);
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
                img.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(relativeLayout.getChildCount()>2){
                    relativeLayout.removeViewAt(2);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    >
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/deck1"
      android:src="@drawable/photo2"
    />
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:id="@+id/deck2"
      android:src="@drawable/photo3"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/deck1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="add image"
    />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="clear"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Warut,I updated the question a little bit,also tried to post some code and xml.Are you sure that the RelativeLayout does not behave like FrameLayout when adding new ImageViews(different layers)?I really hope that there is a solution because I really need this RelativeLayout.....

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure, it ia only a guess that FrameLayout may help. Need to try it right away to prove this. I will be right back after I give it a try ; ) (should be 4 hours till I can).

Comment: Please try the above code. I don't sure how exactly your implementation is. Notice me if it didn't work, so i could help you more.

Comment: Warut,using your code and with some investigations from my side I saw where is my problem - first of all I have to admit that I was wrong about the width and height of two drawables - the one bellow is +10px width and + 10 px height compared with the one that I need to put above.So,when I getLayoutParams from the one bellow and then set them to the one above - the both imageViews use one and the same    layoutparams(the ones for the card above) - that leads to redrawing of the image bellow in order to fit to the image above-new image need to "hide" the whole image bellow....

Comment: What's about if you tried adding the above ImageView without specifying the LayoutParam?

Comment: Thank a lot Warut for your help.It is solved know -here is the code:if(animatingView==null){
    animatingView = new ImageView(this.getDeckView().getCardView().getContext());
    animatingView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(animatingView.getDrawable().getMinimumWidth(), animatingView.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, this.getDeckView().getCardView().getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, this.getDeckView().getCardView().getId());
    animatingView.setLayoutParams(params)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with Scaling the other picture, mby this will help you, tell me if you find any good in this code :)

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(String path, Integer size){
        File f = new File(path);
     try {
         //Decode image size
         BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
         BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

         //The new size we want to scale to
         if(size == 0)
          size = 70;

         //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
         int scale=1;
         while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=size && o.outHeight/scale/2>=size)
             scale*=2;

         //Decode with inSampleSize
         BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         o2.inSampleSize=scale;
         return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
     return null;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,take a look at the update of the question - i hope that I am missing something else and small.